# How to convert integer list to string list?

Tags: python, list

I'm confused by the following code:

```
lst = ['1','2','3']
s = [str(i) for i in lst]
print(s)
```

and

```
lst = ['1','2','3']
for i in lst:
    s = [str(i)]
print(s)
```

Why does the first one print out `['1','2','3']` but the second one only print out `['3']`?
Also, how can I print out `['1','2','3']` with the "normal form" of a `for`-loop like the second one (because I don't understand how the first one works).

Comment: s is overwritten in every iteration in the second code

Comment: In the first example the code first makes the list and then assigns it to s. In the second example s is being overwritten each time. If you want it to work in the second section you would need to create s before the for loop e.g.:

s= []

for i in lst:
    s.append(str(i))

Comment: Strongly suggest you become familiar with the second form and how it works since it's a very useful, powerful, and common Python idiom.